# Read specific key from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am trying to read data from specific `key` in plist file ! but I have no idea why app crashes !!! here is my code :

```
 NSString *loadData = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Dinosaurs" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dinoDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:loadData];
    NSDictionary *dinosaurs = (NSDictionary*)[[dinoDictionary allKeys]objectAtIndex:0];

//app crashes at this line 
    NSString *DINOIMAGE = (NSString*)[dinosaurs valueForKey:@"DINOIMAGE"];

    NSLog(@"%@ , %@",dinosaurs , DINOIMAGE);
```

crash log :

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x7ff7faf0f790> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key DINOIMAGE.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

plist file :
[image]

Comment: Here is my answer : As long as you do not even tell us , what crash at which line you get , nobody can help you !!!

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad sorry check my edited question

Comment: I don't think that `dinosaurs` might be really a `NSDictionary`. It's probablly a `NSString`, which seems more logical.

Comment: There's a general problem: The first object of `allKeys` can never be a dictionary. And do you know what `valueForKey` really does respectively what key value coding is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You concealed that the requested dictionary is a sub-dictionary with key `SCELIDOSAURUS`

```
NSString *loadData = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Dinosaurs" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dinoDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: loadData];
NSDictionary *scelidosaurus = (NSDictionary *)dinoDictionary[@"SCELIDOSAURUS"]
NSString *DINOIMAGE = (NSString *)scelidosaurus[@"DINOIMAGE"];
NSLog(@"%@, %@", dinoDictionary, DINOIMAGE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're grabbing the first key in the `dinoDictionary` and using it as if it were a dictionary (it's a NSString) here:

```
NSDictionary *dinosaurs = (NSDictionary*)[[dinoDictionary allKeys]objectAtIndex:0];
//app crashes at this line 
NSString *DINOIMAGE = (NSString*)[dinosaurs valueForKey:@"DINOIMAGE"];
```

That's what the error message says: *The NSString class cannot be queried for the key `DINOIMAGE`*.

You should simply query the `dinoDictionary` with the key `DINOIMAGE` as follows:

```
NSString *loadData = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Dinosaurs" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dinoDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: loadData];
NSString *DINOIMAGE = (NSString *)dinoDictionary[@"DINOIMAGE"];
NSLog(@"%@, %@", dinoDictionary, DINOIMAGE);
```

Comment: first of all DINOIMAGE returns me null ! and second as I said i need to look for a specific key for example a key called `name` in the `4th` item !